# C# build without unnecessary dependencies of a reference

Tags: c#, optimization, dll, build, dependency-management

I have project X, which depends on project Y. Project Y depends on two dlls: dll A and dll B. Despite project Xis only using a functionality of project Y that depends on dll a, dll b is being pulled into project X's build output. If I remove dll B from build output and run project Y.exe everything works without a difference.

Is this expected and how build process work by default in c# projects?

What should I do to get a build output without dll b? Creating  seperate projects for each functionality using dll A or dll B ?

Any build/dependency optimization tools out there to handle this case ?

Comment: Currently, no. In the future, it might. .NET Native has the capabilities to merge all assemblies to one, and shake off all the bits you don't actually need, but its adoption beyond UWP is too slow, so the whole .NET world is waiting.